# JAVAFX Table View Wrapped Text Font Color

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

```
private TableColumn<FundedResearch, String> makeStringColumnRes(String columnName, String propertyName, int prefWidth) {
    TableColumn<FundedResearch, String> column = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FundedResearch, String>(propertyName));
    column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<FundedResearch, String>, TableCell<FundedResearch, String>>() {
      @Override public TableCell<FundedResearch, String> call(TableColumn<FundedResearch, String> soCalledFriendStringTableColumn) {
        return new TableCell<FundedResearch, String>() {
            private Text text;
          @Override public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {

                text=new Text(item.toString());
                text.setWrappingWidth(column.getWidth());
                text.setStyle("-fx-font-color:#FFFFFF");
                column.setStyle("-fx-font-color:#FFFFFF");
                this.setWrapText(true);
                setGraphic(text);
                setStyle("-fx-font-color:#FFFFFF");
            }
          }
        };
      }
    });
    if(prefWidth!=0){
    column.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
    column.setMaxWidth(prefWidth);
    column.setMinWidth(prefWidth);
    }

    return column;
  }
```

i have this method that is called to make table column.  i have wrapped the String to Cell to make all text visible. the problem is i cant make the font color white. Share your ideas . Thank you. :) those styles set inside the `if statement` is what i have tried so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one also works fine.

```
text.setFill(Color.WHITE);
```

just got it last few hours ago

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property to use is not `-fx-font-color`:

If should be `-fx-fill`. You can find this information here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape (Navigate from `Text` to the first superclass that supports color, in this case `Shape`).

Also you need to handle the case when there's no item apropriately. Otherwise the `text` will still be displayed when the cell is empty. Furthermore it's not necessary to recreate the `Text` objects every time the `item` changes:

```
column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<FundedResearch, String>, TableCell<FundedResearch, String>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<FundedResearch, String> call(TableColumn<FundedResearch, String> soCalledFriendStringTableColumn) {
        return new TableCell<FundedResearch, String>() {
            private Text text = new Text();

            {
                text.setStyle("-fx-fill: white;");
                text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    text.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(text);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```